# How to use geom_freqpoly in R for a frequency distribution?

Tags: r, ggplot2, frequency-distribution

I have a large dataframe with polygons (>40 000 records) called `data`. Each polygon has a certain area with values between 1000 m² and 1096345 m². The smallest polygons are the most frequent. I want to show the frequency distribution in a line plot, instead of a histogram. So the x-axis should be the area in logarithmic scale - so from 1000 to 1100000 and then you have the y-axis. I don't think it's needed to make that axis logarithmic.

So far this is my code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = area)) +
  geom_freqpoly()+
  scale_x_log10() +
  theme_minimal()
```

And then the plot looks like this:
[image]

But I don't know whether this is correct. I think the code isn't complete. When I add the `binwidth`, it shows weird plots. How can I complete the code, or are there better solutions then using geom_freqpoly?

Comment: I think this looks exactly as expected. The areas of your polygons seem to approximately follow a power law. You can't really use `binwidth` if you have a logarithmic axis, because the bins need to increase logarithmically in width. Setting e.g. `bins = 50` should work.

Comment: An alternative would be `geom_density`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks for your response. I will leave the code as it is. I have an additional question. Why does the graph shows values that are lower than 1000 m², although 1000 m² is the minimum area?

Comment: It doesn't really show values below 1000. A freqpoly is just like a histogram, except instead of bars there is a line joining where the top of the bars would be. Below 1000 there is a bin with a count of 0, and just above 1000 there is a count of 6000. There is a line drawn between these two bins, so it looks like there could be values below 1000. This is a downside of freqpoly from which a good old histogram doesn't suffer. You could try setting `limits = c(999, 1e6)` inside `scale_x_log10` to compensate I suppose.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you very much! I adjusted the code with `bins = 50` and `limits = c(1000, 100000)` like you suggested. Then I have a nice descending curve (reverse relationship with size). (I also added breaks and labels for the size being 1000, 10000 and 100000.)